# Como funciona chave estrangeira em c#?

Tags: c#

Tenho duas tabelas Contato(Homem) e Mulher.
O homem pode ter várias mulheres e uma mulher é para um homem.

```
 public class Contato {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public String usuario { get; set; }
    public String nome { get; set; }
    public String senha { get; set; }
    public List<Mulher> listaMulher { get; set; }
}

  public class Mulher
  {
    public int idM { get; set; }
    public Contato id { get; set; }
    public String nome { get; set; }
    public String formacao { get; set; }

  }
```

Seria dessa forma?
Mas e a mulher como posso adicionar uma chave para a mulher? Como ficaria isso na classe main?

Comment: Só para confirmar, você está usando EF, certo?

Comment: O que é EF??????????

Comment: [Entity Framework](https://www.asp.net/entity-framework). Se não está usando, tem que nos dizer qual tecnologia pretende usar.

Comment: Não estou usando e não pretendo usar. Aqui no momento só estou fazendo tudo na mão mesmo...

Comment: Se você está fazendo um *framework* de acesso a BD *inhouse* cabe a você definir a API. Caso contrário você vai ter que escolher um *framework* existente. Aí depende de você para decidir o que melhor atente, existem várias opções, EF, NHibernate, Dapper, etc. Pesquise e  depois adicione detalhes a pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Em um Relacionamento um para muitos

Data Annotations

```
 public class Student
    {
        public Student() { }

        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public string StudentName { get; set; }   
        public int StdandardRefId { get; set; }           
        [ForeignKey("StandardRefId")]
        public virtual Standard Standard { get; set; }
    }

    public class Standard
    {
        public Standard()
        {
            StudentsList = new List<Student>();
        }
        public int StandardId { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
    }
```

em  Fluent API

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
            //configure one-to-many
            modelBuilder.Entity<Standard>()
                        .HasMany<Student>(s => s.Students) Standard has many Students
                        .WithRequired(s => s.Standard)  Student require one Standard
                        .HasForeignKey(s => s.StdId);Student includes specified foreignkey property name for Standard
    }
```

fonte:http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: Isso aí é o que? Vc está usando entity framework?

Comment: sim entity framework, mas segunda opção serve também para mapeamento do Fluent Hibernate

Comment: Mas considere a pergunta sem a utilização de Entity framework pq aqui na empresa eles não utilizam.

Comment: pensando como orientação objeto é mesma coisa so ultima parte que não existe